# Как задать счетчик отрисовок?

Tags: c#, winforms

Всем привет. Мне нужно реализовать отрисовку квадрата с повторяющимися квадратиками по углам.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Lab4
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
     public Form1()
     {
       InitializeComponent();
     }

     public void DrawRectangles(Graphics g, Pen pen, Point startPoint, Size size)
     {
        if (size.Width < 40 || size.Height < 40) return;
        startPoint.Offset(-size.Width / 2, -size.Height / 2);
        var rect = new Rectangle(startPoint, size);
        g.DrawRectangle(pen, rect);

        var newSize = new Size(size.Width / 2, size.Height / 2);
        var points = new List
     {
            startPoint,
            new Point(startPoint.X + size.Width, startPoint.Y),
            new Point(startPoint.X, startPoint.Y + size.Height),
            new Point(startPoint.X + size.Width, startPoint.Y + size.Height)
     };

     points.ForEach(pt =>
     {
     DrawRectangles(g, pen, pt, newSize);
     });
}

private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
      var pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 3);
      var startPoint = new Point(0, 0);
      startPoint.Offset(Width / 2, Height / 2);
      var size = new Size(Height / 2, Height / 2);
      DrawRectangles(e.Graphics, pen, startPoint, size);
}

private void Form1_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      Refresh();

}

private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
         if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
         Application.Exit();
}
}
}
```

Вот мой код, квадрат отрисовывается, и по углам так же отрисовка есть, но она неправильная, т.е тут отрисовка зависит от размера который я задам , если задам <150 То вообще ничего не отрисует, а нужно задать как бы счетчик отрисовок. Как это можно сделать?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Отформатировал.

Comment: Пока вопрос не понятен, что по углам, где по углам, как это работает? Без вставки вашего кода ко мне в проект точно не сможете объяснить? Счетчик отрисовок, это кадры в секунду, или что?

Comment: Я добавил картинку

Comment: Понимаете, у меня можно отрисовывать квадраты по углам до бесконечности если задать размер 16, а если я задам размер < 150, то отрисовывать ничего не будет, лишь один квадрат по центру. Мне нужно чтобы допустим больше 2 шагов как представлено на рисунке отрисовки не было.

Comment: Это скриншот или набросок в паинте? Смотрю на код и не могу понять, как он такие неровные прямоугольники рисует.

Comment: Добавил 2 скрина. На 1 если задам размер <150 рисует 1 квадрат по центу, на 2 если задам <16 рисует множество.

Comment: Кажется начало доходить. Вам нужно нарисовать 2 уровня фрактала. Сделайте так, чтобы метод принимал `int` переменную как аргумент, затем минусуйте из нее единичку и передавайте во все последующие рекурсивные вызовы. Если 0 - возврат из метода.

Comment: У Вас нет примера кода? не доходит  как это реализовать

Comment: `public void DrawRectangles(Graphics g, Pen pen, Point startPoint, Size size, int count)`. Потом `if (count == 0) return;`, потом `count--;`, потом `points.ForEach(pt => DrawRectangles(g, pen, pt, newSize, count))`. А из `Form_Paint` вот так `DrawRectangles(e.Graphics, pen, startPoint, size, 2)`

Comment: Как же я Вам благодарен, спасибо большое. Теперь он рисует так как надо))

Comment: Извините за глупый вопрос, а почему count--, ну т.е я понимаю что идёт понижение на единицу, но как так получается что если убрать count-- то только в 1 углу отрисовка произойдет, а если count-- то во всех четырех?

Comment: `count` локальная переменная, она размножается вместе с квадратиками, то есть у каждого квадратика она - своя. Она передается точно так же как и точки на углах, вы же в каждый новый вызов передаете деленный на 2 размер и новую точку, верно? Ну вот с `count` то же самое. Вопрос действительно глупый :)

Comment: А в 1 углу, потому что у вас никогда не будет выполнен `return` из метода, потому что `count` никогда не станет 0, бесконечная рекурсия. У вас еще и приложение висит при этом, если не заметили. :)

Comment: Понял, спасибо большое ещё раз))